# Problems with functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, web, backend

```
function getParentID() {
    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $pageID = url_to_postid($url);
    $pageID = trim($pageID);
    return $pageID;
}

function OrderFieldsQuery($args) {

    //->> WORKS WITH HARD-CODED ID'S
    $args['post_parent'] = 52;

    $args['post_parent'] = getParentID();
    // Doesn't work in that way, even function returns same value;

    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query', 'OrderFieldsQuery', 10, 1); // add key to filter
```

**Additional example: 
**

```
 global $wp;
    $currentUrl = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
    $ID =  url_to_postid($currentUrl);
    $args['post_parent'] = $ID;
    $args['post_parent1'] = 52;
    if ($args['post_parent'] === $args['post_parent1'])
        $args['equal'] = true;
    // Doesn't work in that way, even function returns same value;

    return $args;
```

Output i get on this.........:

Array ( [post_parent] => 52 [post_parent1] => 52 [equal] => 1 )

So they are equal but it works only when hard-coded.

Comment: What does `var_dump(getParentID())` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get page url from below code

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(),$wp->request));
```

Now use below code to get the page id

```
  $postid = url_to_postid( $current_url );
```

Now you will get the id

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function OrderFieldsQuery($args) {

    //->> WORKS WITH HARD-CODED ID'S
    $args['post_parent'] = 52;

    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
    $pageID = url_to_postid($url);
    $pageID = trim($pageID);
    $args['post_parent'] = $pageID;
    // Doesn't work in that way, even function returns same value;

    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query', 'OrderFieldsQuery', 10, 1); // add key to filter
```